# Missing Dock Structure in Alien: Covenant

Tags: prometheus, alien-covenant

This seems to me like something that may ending being a mystery or something of an "oops" thing. I am not entirely sure which way it goes for now.

In Alien: Covenant, In one of David's flashback to when he arrived to the white people planet. He was docking with a huge floating curved stapler (not sure how better to describe the shape) structure before that horrible thing happened.

Earlier before the above event, David flew/crash, not sure which since he clearly lied about that bit, into the forest close by to the Necropolis. The floating stapler dock structure is nowhere to be found. Could they have escaped their own weapon in the stapler structure? I am asking this because in Prometheus their starship are capable of atmosphere manipulation and perhaps could have escape that horrible event. Or were they caught and if that is true where did they fell/crash? There are a few aerial flyby especially with the crane scene. All we see of the Necropolis is stone after stone. Not even a single crater to explain the disappear of a HUGE freaking structure?!

I sincerely hope that this was an intent teaser meant to lead to the next Movie rather than a production mistake!

Comment: The structure appears to be an automated receiving dock for the ship. When David moved the ship away for whatever reason, it probably retracted back underground.

Comment: I can see a few problems with your theory. First) Where would the hangar door be? It would have to be VERY large to just give it enough clearance to get in. Two) why would you in a starship that can fly away from the horror happening below. Go back and dock there? When you can instead fly away or something else. Three) From what little of necropolis that we seen. There isn't any hangar space anywhere. Only one time we see an underground cavern is when David lure one of the crew member toward the eggs. That cave doesn't have room for covenant shuttle. Forget about fit a horseshoe starship.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the lack of scenes...or any kind of way to actually discover where the structure could have gone to, One can conjecture that the Necropolis isn't the most ideal place to leave giant machinery floating above and infact, [in the beginning of the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-v-bxPsxpE0), one can see the device floating into position as David arrives.

Concluding that it must likely also float away when unneeded.

On top of that, that specific ship (or kind of ship) may have had some kind of significant meaning to the Engineers...Thousands upon thousands of them have gathered to meet the (what they think) returning citizens. The docking device could likely be designed for only those specific ships and used in specific ways.

Considering they are ultra advanced in nanotechnology and AI and a space-faring/warring society. It's unlikely that they have Ziggurats and other 'early civilization' style architecture with likely some kind of religious meaning (under the heavy handed assumption of the movies obvious religious connection) and then also leave a giant space docking station floating above it.

The Docking station likely left when David landed on the surface finally, or was automatically called away.