# How did the acid burnt Man in Alien Covenant die?

Tags: plot-explanation, alien-covenant

This is a different subject than [my last dock structure question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/73774/49) I asked earlier. However this is a smaller spoiler.

In Alien Covenant, when David watched over the man, whose character/Actor name escape me at the moment, that got his face burned. I believe there were at least "two distinct" different opportunities for him to be impregnated with Xenomorph. I am trying to figure out which one was the most likely. He got his face burn off after a briefly being "face hugged" by a facehugger and someone manage to cut it off. Thus resulting in the acid burn. Was the brief contact enough?

I thought about an alternative scenario which would have the same consequence both literally and figuratively.

Keep in mind that David and not Walter manage to get on-board the fleeing cargo lifter while the audience don't know about David replacing Walter. At the very end David reveal that he managed to save at least two facehugger encapsulated in something inside his own body. Would it have been far more likely that he took out one of those and impregnated him when he is heavily sedated by putting the facehugger inside his body while it is very tiny and most likely to success with the payload? Keep in mind that the two other crew were completely pre-occupied with dealing with an adult Xenomorph running around the cargo lifter. They would not been in a position to be aware of David's actions.

Comment: There is really no necessity for spoiler blocks in question bodies and when overused to the extreme, they're *actively discouraged*. For more information, see [this meta discussion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/how-to-deal-with-spoilers), as well as [this one](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/82/49) and the corresponding section in the [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please don't turn your question into a huge empty box, rather than for it to make sense.

Comment: It spoil a huge surprise of the end of the movie especially with respect to David. Nevermind that this movie is still in theater!

Comment: Yes, but you do so *after* people actually clicked through to a question about *Alien: Covenant* and its story and read your question. They're basically on their own after this point (especially since you even warn them in the first sentence). You haven't seen it and you fully read a question about its story? Tough luck! The title on the other hand shouldn't spoil anything, but it doesn't seem to anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that contact was enough. Actually, there was a part that caught my attention when they are escaping in the cargo lifter, and that I think it's when he really gets infected

> David/Walter changes the burnt man's face bandage for no apparent reason as soon as he gets into the cargo lifter. My guess was that he put an alien capsule inside the bandage while the man was in a state of semiconsciousness so he didn't really realize what was happening and couldn't warn the others.

Then it was just a matter of waiting.

Answer (score 0):

His name was [Lope](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0569060/?ref_=ch_mv) and although brief, it was enough time, at least according [to this review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUETfsxRbEk) (starting at 18:20ish), which makes the best case that can be made.

Edit: To directly answer the question in the title, he would have died due to an alien busting out of his chest.

Comment: Yes the question about is when did he become infected and by what means? We never actually see his body and what left of the crew of covenant walked up to the medbay and saw blood all over. They didn't even bother to inspect the body and run off. So we can't determine anything much from the body itself as it wasn't showed. Edit: I just watched the review and I feel it is more of a subjective conjecture. I am not aware of any instance where facehugger had contact for 4 seconds and manage to infect from there.